# Script to copy one column data to another column

Tags: sql, shell, ksh, cql, cqlsh

I am writing a script to copy one column data to another column.
Tried with following logic bud didnt worked out-
o/p- number of parameter is 0.

My Logic-
•   I got the keys from the admintable and then copied the data to some updateupdateStatement file. 
•   Using awk command I copied specific column data to some temp file
•   Then prepared an update statement and then executed it.

```
          #!/bin/ksh
          #
          # Script to Populate cross_refs based on what is in cross_references
          #
          #

          echo "number of parameters is $#"

           if [ $# != 1 ]; then
           USAGE="USAGE: $0 cassPassword"
           echo ${USAGE}
           exit 1
           fi

           cassPassword=$1

            #Add column to admin table
            #echo "alter table to add column..."
            #echo "ALTER TABLE admin.product ADD cross_refs Map<String,String>;" > updateTable.cql

            #cqlsh -u dgadmin -p ${cassPassword} -f updateTable.cql

            echo "get keys from cassandra"
            echo "copy admin.product (cross_references) to 'updateupdateProductStatement.cql';" > copyInputs.cql
            cqlsh -u dgadmin -p ${cassPassword} -f copyInputs.cql


            #Convert file that Cassandra created from DOS to Unix
            echo "DOS to Unix conversion..."
            tr -d '\015' <updateupdateProductStatement.cql >updateupdateProductStatement2.cql

            cat updateupdateProductStatement2.cql  >tempFile
            sed -i "s/^/update admin.product set cross_refs = '/" tempFile

            #execute the updated .cql file to run all the update statements
             echo "executing updateupdateProductStatement.cql..."
             cqlsh -u dgadmin -p ${cassPassword} -f tempFile
```

Comment: your tags say bash but your script is ksh. consider adding a ksh tag and removing the bash tag so that your question reaches its intended audience

Answer (score 0):

I'm not absolutely certain I understand the intent of your script, but I can pick out one line that looks suspect...

```
cat updateFlatFileInputStatements2.cql |awk -F'\t' '{ 19                1              2}'  >tempFile
```

I think you want to print columns 19, 1 and 2 to your output...

```
awk -F'\t' 'BEGIN { OFS="         " }{ print $19, $1, $2 }' updateFlatFileInputStatements2.cql > tempFile
```

Better is to do all the manipulation of `tempFile` in **awk**

```
awk -F'\t' "{ print \"update admin.product set my_refs = \" \$19 \" where id = \" $1 \" and effective_date = \" $2 \"';\"" updateFlatFileInputStatements2.cql > tempFile
```

Then again, I don't see in your file where `tempFile` is used... or where `updateFlatFileInputStatements2.cql` is generated.  Looks like this piece of code is doing nothing?

`updateupdateStatement.cql` ... don't know where that comes from.  This then is stripped to form `updateupdateStatement2.cql` ... which then is manipulated to become `tempFile` but... you don't use `tempFile` -- instead you send `updateupdateStatement2.cql` to `cqlsh`.  The bug may be that you intended to send `tempFile` instead to your final `cqlsh`.

Comment: Hi Michael, Thanks for pointing me out few important things. I have updated my post , it seems everyting is fine except am getting "incomplete statement at the end of the file". please advice.

Comment: Well... The thing is that the rewriting of the question makes the answer just "go away"... It would be better to revert your question & ask another later....  What I see above though is that you likely need to quote your password -- double-quotes around "$1" and "$cassPassword".  It is also better form to eliminate the cat with... `sed -e "s/^/update admin.product set cross_refs = '/" updateupdateProductStatement2 > tempFile`  think the new sed statement is missing a `s/$/'/` maybe???